# How to display the data detector's context menu in cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, contextmenu, detect

I want to programmingly display the following menus when the mouse hovering on address/url/phone number/event... text,just like the "Mail" app,how to implement? thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

[image]